# How to find just one document with Restivus and Curl

Tags: mongodb, rest, curl, meteor

I have a simple beginners problem with using Restivus.

In my app.js I have declared:

```
Players = new Mongo.Collection("players");
```

and later on:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // Global configuration
  Api = new Restivus({
    useDefaultAuth: true,
    prettyJson: true
  });

  // Generates: GET/POST on /api/v1/players, and GET/PUT/DELETE on     /api/v1/players/:id
  // for Meteor.users collection (works on any Mongo collection)
  Api.addCollection(Players);
  // That's it! Many more options are available if needed...
}
```

I then start "meteor mongo"

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.players.insert({username:"Kalle", location:"Home"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

meteor:PRIMARY> db.players.insert({username:"Pelle", location:"Away"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

meteor:PRIMARY> db.players.find({});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56598d83846a7b53e8a1176b"), "username" : "Kalle","location" : "Home" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56598d8c846a7b53e8a1176c"), "username" : "Pelle", "location" : "Away" }
```

And when I try it using CURL I get:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/players
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "_str": "56598d83846a7b53e8a1176b"
      },
      "username": "Kalle",
      "location": "Home"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "_str": "56598d8c846a7b53e8a1176c"
      },
      "username": "Pelle",
      "location": "Away"
    }
  ]
```

BUT when I then try to find one particular document:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/players/56598d83846a7b53e8a1176b
{
  "status": "fail",
  "message": "Item not found"
}
```

Why doesn't it find the document and whats the deal with the:

```
"_id": {
    "_str": "56598d83846a7b53e8a1176b"
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `meteor mongo` simply opens a MongoDB shell, the documents were created with an ObjectId for an `_id` (which is the default type for MongoDB ids).

Meteor defaults to random strings for `_id`s. Therefore, the `_id` in your example is not simply the string that you see, but the entire ObjectId containing it.

To make it work, either explicitly set an `_id` in the mongo shell or (probably better) use `meteor shell` to insert the documents directly from the Meteor server.

Comment: Great! It worked fine when I did:  "mongo shell"  followed by "Players.insert({username:"Sven", location:"somewhere"});" After that the curl command http://localhost/api/players/:id worked fine!

Comment: Do you mean `meteor shell`?